# How to use symlinks in magento?

Tags: magento, subdomain

How to use symlinks in magento?

This is the scenario:

I have a subdomain store.example.com (say), it has 4 websites (de,fr,au,af).
I want each of these websites to link to store.de.example.com , store.fr.example.com, store.au.example.com and store.af.example.com respectively.
So that I can run each of these magento websites individually.

Answer (score 2):

My usual approach for setting up Magento multisite environment.

Here are few additional goals that I’d like to achieve when doing this: core code out of the way , clean public folders, packed  for easier deployment and testing.

```
magento_base/
htdocs/
htdocs/website_01/
htdocs/website_01/index.php
htdocs/website_01/.htaccess <-- symlink
htdocs/website_01/js/ <--symlink
htdocs/website_01/skin/ <--symlink
htdocs/website_01/media/ <--symlink
htdocs/website_01/errors/ <--symlink
htdocs/website_01/downloader/  <--symlink
htdocs/website_02/
```

Set up your magento isntallation to magento_base folder and right next to it (or any place you need or your virtual-host makes them) you’d make a folder for each of your subdomain, website (dependent of your multisite goals). Next we symlink public parts of magento to this folder and make a copy of index.php and change path for including Mage.php and set your website or store code at the end of it.

*note that if you have few sites  then you can make htdocs folder inside your magento_base for easier deployment  and map your domains inside that folder*

Next step is to point your domain, subdomain and map it to right website folder and you are good to go:

- You get your codebase out of the public folder by pointing domains to public folder and symlinking Magento’s few public needs
- Upgrades won’t mess with your symlinked files and you don’t have to change server configuration files
- If you use git then you can have those symlinks pointed to stage, live branch checkouts and just push your changes to production or stage env’s
- You can test inside magento base folder on your test-server without conflicting your production settings and setup different sites (sites can be accessed by site or store code) 
  client is pointed to public folder to upload his other stuff , campaigns, blogs whatever and that won’t be mixing with magento_base folder and you can make rules to include/exclude from your deployment procedure. No more crap inside.